# Do chromosomes uncoil in interphase II?

Tags: cell-biology, meiosis, cell-division

During interphase II, there is no S phase in which DNA replicates. However, in this stage, do the chromosomes remain wound? Or have they unwound into chromatin form, and recondense during prophase II?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases the chromosomes do undergo some dispersion, they do not reach the extremely extended state of the interphase nucleus, this all happens in [telophase -I](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis#Phases). It would be correct to refer to the stage between two meiotic divisions as [**interkinesis**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interkinesis) which is generally short lived.

The prophase-II is initiated immediately after cytokinesis, usually before the chromosomes have fully elongated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the diagram found on [this](http://naturalsciences.sdsu.edu/classes/lab2.5/semnet/interphase_II.htm) site, chromosomes do unwind during Interphase II of meiosis.

[Sparknotes](http://www.sparknotes.com/biology/cellreproduction/meiosis/section3.rhtml), although it's not necessarily a reputable scientific source, seems to concur:

> Once the nuclear envelope has re-formed after the first meiotic division, the cell enters a short interphase. This interphase is not as specific as mitotic interphase; during meiotic interphase, chromosomes may decondense as the cell waits to proceed with meiosis.

Finally, [this](http://www.macroevolution.net/interkinesis.html) website provides a clarification in stating that there is no true "interphase" between meiosis I and II (I guess true interphase would be marked by replication of DNA which, as you state, does not occur):

> The period between meiosis I and meiosis II is sometimes called "interphase," this is confusing because it is not a true interphase such as that seen between rounds of mitosis because no synthesis occurs (all chromosomes have two chromatids throughout this stage).

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the very own existence of an interphase II between meiosis I and meiosis II is highly questionable, and a search on Pubmed found an article by *[Vernet et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24967676)*, according to which interphase-II exists only in male meiosis.